How to resize an image in Gradio?
I'm looking for an approach to resize an image as a header in Gradio generated UI to be smaller.
According to a closed issue on their Github, I followed the following manner:
import gradio as gr

with gr.Blocks() as app:
    gr.Image("logo.png", label="Top Image").style(width=600, height=400)
    app.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7860, debug=True)

But it raises:
AttributeError: 'Markdown' object has no attribute 'style'. Did you mean: 'scale'?

I also tried using the Markdown() or HTML() method rather than Image() however, the issue is with this approach it cannot load an image locally.
Here's the thing I've done so far:
import gradio as gr

def greet(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"

# Load your local image
image_path = "/file/logo.png"

with gr.Blocks() as demo:
    html_header = f"""
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <img src="{image_path}" alt="Header Image" width="200" height="100">
    </div>
    """
    gr.HTML(html_header)

    name_input = gr.Textbox(label="Enter your name:")
    submit_button = gr.Button("Submit")
    output = gr.Textbox(label="Greeting:")

    submit_button.click(fn=greet, inputs=name_input, outputs=output)

demo.launch()

I also tried image_path = "/file=logo.png", image_path = "/file/logo.png", image_path = "file=logo.png", and image_path = "./logo.png" routes without any results.
I should add that the logo and the .py file are next to each other.

Well, the RIGHT answer is to resize your image locally.  Otherwise, you're using up bandwidth to send out a large file that won't be used.

every web developer will say that you should resize images before you even start web server,

@TimRoberts It doesn't work to resize the image itself. Still, it stretches the image!

maybe you should use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox to check if CSS changes its size - and set own CSS

if I understand documentation for Image you may do Image(..., width=..., height=...)

what "closed issue on their Github" do you means? You should add link in question (not in comments)

if you problem with path to image then open working version and use Ctrl+U in web browser to see source HTML and see what path it uses.

Documentation for Image shows that you can use
Image(..., width=..., height=...)

I test it and it works but it can't be smaller than width=160.
And it needs to change also min_width= to smaller value because it has default value 160

If you don't need label and download button then you can uses
Image(..., show_label=False, show_download_button=False)


If you want to put own <img src="..."> then it can make problem because DevTools in Firefox/Chrome shows that it uses path like this
http://0.0.0.0:7860/file=/tmp/user/1000/gradio/f1ca8fcde634bae0360273c73b61af0bac43f7a8/logo.png

Maybe there is random value or maybe it is hash value calculated for this file.
I checked it created file on disk (on Linux)
/tmp/user/1000/gradio/f1ca8fcde634bae0360273c73b61af0bac43f7a8/logo.png


I found that you can use local file if you add it to allowed_path in app.launch()
src="/file=logo.png"
app.launch(..., allowed_paths=["logo.png"])
image_path = "logo.png"
gr.HTML(f"""<img src="/file={image_path}" width="100" height="100">""")
    
app.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7860, debug=True, 
           allowed_paths=[image_path])

You may also use folder (absolute or relative)
src="/file=/some/folder/logo.png"
app.launch(..., allowed_paths=["/some/folder/"])
folder = "/other/folder"

image_path_1 = f"{folder}/logo.png"
gr.HTML(f"""<img src="/file={image_path_1}" width="100" height="100">""")

image_path_2 = f"{folder}/other.png"
gr.HTML(f"""<img src="/file={image_path_2}" width="100" height="100">""")
    
app.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7860, debug=True, 
           allowed_paths=[folder])

It can be relative folder
src="/file=subfolder/images/logo.png"
app.launch(..., allowed_paths=["subfolder/images/"])
or you may create absolute path
absolute_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "subfolder", "images")

and this path you have to use in src="/file=..." and add to allowed_paths.

There is also set_static_paths to add folder with static elements - like layout graphics, logo.
gr.set_static_paths(paths=["static/images/"])

image_path = "static/images/logo.png"

gr.HTML(f"""<img src="/file={image_path}" width="100" height="100">""")

and this doesn't need to add to allowed_paths

great thanks. for me the path is "/file=/tmp/gradio/5536ae34b7f5a7218f84346228f4ef0513698dd0/logo.png". Isn't there any way to serve this image by the relative path instead of this absolute path specific from /tmp/gradio.../?

this path is created automatically by gradio but I wonder if would work "/file=/full/path/to/other/place". With absolute path it may work but I wouldn't expect it for relative path

If I put image without hash like /tmp/user/1000/gradio/logo.png then works src="/file=/tmp/user/1000/gradio/logo.png" but it doesn't work if I try to use other folder. If I open directly http://0.0.0.0:7860/file=/other/folder/image.png  then it sends JSON message with "detail: File not allowed /other/folder/image.png"

I found that you can use local file /file=logo.png but you have to add it to lauch(..., allowed_paths=["logo.png"]). You may also allow for folder lauch(..., allowed_paths=["/some/folder"]) and /file=/some/folder/logo.png /file=/some/folder/other.png. I didn't test for relative folder.

I found also set_static_paths which allows to add some folder
